# create the table in horizontally from json response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the json response which I want to  move the table data month wise.I want to get the sum of the actual,dso and revenue for each month in horizontal wise and need to get the total of the each column.
Now I have the data for 3 months APR,MAY,JUN.I want to get a data as register in laravel blade from the response  as shown in image
[image]

$am_details returns below response.

```
{
"AMSummaryDetail": [
    {
        "AccountManager": "arjunakani.arjunan",
        "CustomerName": "ACCESSDATA GROUP, INC.",
        "ForecastTypeName": "EN",
        "Unit":"SE",
        "ValueDetails": [
            {
                "ActualValue": "155",
                 "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "Apr-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "156",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "May-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "157",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "Jun-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "AccountManager": "arjunakani.arjunan",
        "CustomerName": "ACCESSDATA GROUP, INC.",
        "ForecastTypeName": "EE",
        "Unit":"SE",
        "ValueDetails": [
            {
                "ActualValue": "83198",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "Apr-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "0",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "May-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "59292",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "Jun-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "AccountManager": "arjunakani.arjunan",
        "CustomerName": "ACCESSDATA GROUP, INC.",
        "ForecastTypeName": "EE",
        "Unit":"Testing",
        "ValueDetails": [
            {
                "ActualValue": "0",
                "DSO": "5",
                "Month": "Apr-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "0",
                "DSO": "55",
                "Month": "May-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "0",
                "DSO": "5",
                "Month": "Jun-20",
                "NetRevenue": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    
    {
        "AccountManager": "sanjana.natarajan",
        "CustomerName": "APEX 2000 Inc",
        "ForecastTypeName": "EE",
        "ValueDetails": [
            {
                "ActualValue": "0",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "Apr-20",
                "NetRevenue": "15"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "0",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "May-20",
                "NetRevenue": "-5"
            },
            {
                "ActualValue": "0",
                "DSO": "0",
                "Month": "Jun-20",
                "NetRevenue": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"ErrorDetails": null,
"ErrorInfo": null,
"count": 126
 }
```

I have tried as

```
@foreach($am_details as $am_detail)

<tr>
 <td>{{$am_detail->CustomerName}}</td>
 <td>{{$am_detail->AccountManager}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand - what is the problem or error you are getting please? Is the image you are getting what you're currently doing, or what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thats I'm trying to da

Comment: so what is your issue when trying to do this?